# How to access Seaside control panel in Pharo 3.0?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

The Pharo By Example book says to open it through the Tools submenu - but I don't see this in Pharo 3.0

Is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use Seaside Control Panel because it was made in OmniBrowser which is not included in Pharo 2.0+

Instead, you can use:

```
ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 7070.
```

and

```
ZnZincServerAdaptor stop.
```

Comment: You can now use the Seaside Control Panel in Pharo3 with Seaside3+